# Showing post along with sidebar widget from wordpress to static page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have website which is in main root directory:

> http://example.com

and wordpress blog in sub-folder

> http://example.com/blog/

Now I'm trying to show recently added post on home page ( index.php ) outside of wordpress. So far is working and the post body is showed on the page. This is how I've made it ( from wordpress documentation )

```
<?php
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');



   $posts = get_posts('numberposts=1&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
   foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

      <h1> <?php the_title(); ?> </h1>
      <h2> <?php the_date(); echo "<br />";?></h2>
      <h3 style="color: white;"> <?php the_content(); ?> </h3>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

It is very basic example. My question is it possible to fetch and show whole post page? Like header, widgets which are on right side, post and comments/comment form?

Answer (score 0):

Just call the sidebar with [get_sidebar(); function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sidebar/). Example in your case

```
<?php
     define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
     require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
     $posts = get_posts('numberposts=1&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
     foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

         <h1> <?php the_title(); ?> </h1>
         <h2> <?php the_date(); echo "<br />";?></h2>
         <h3 style="color: white;"> <?php the_content(); ?> </h3>
<?php endforeach; ?>

// calling the sidebar
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

Now the sidebar will be visible also. May require some html/css tweaking.